# cbind a long list in R using list

Tags: r, cbind

i have a huge number of vectors in R, all with the same length, say: `x1,x2,...,x1000000`
and i want to `cbind` some of into one single dataframe. I have the list of the names of vectors that i want to combine, say `name_list <- c("x3","x47847","x930233")` of vectors `x3,x47847,x930233`
So normally we would just use `cbind(x3,x47847,x930233)`. But since the number of vectors is huge, and all i have is the name list, is there any way i can just do the `cbind` with `name_list`?

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: Try `do.call(cbind, your_list[name_list])`.

Comment: A very underhanded technique would be to make a list of all your vectors (`as.list(mget(name_list))`) and then set that list's class to `data.frame`. You must also specify the attribute `row.names` manually (as a vector with the same length of one of your columns) to make it behave correctly. This will bypass a lot of checks that `cbind` would do so use at your own risk.

Comment: I guess you want `do.call(cbind,mget(name_list))`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding yes that is the sane solution. But less fun :D

Comment: @Ottie Yes, you are right. I am just aware that I did the same thing as you.